# time span for facebook (ios Application)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I want to calculate time span for twitter and facebook.

For twitter:-Tue Jul 19 11:08:46 +0000 2011

for facebook:-2011-07-18T15:25:09+0000

I want to convert it in to like,1 hrs ago,60 min ago,2 mint ago etc.

And how to compare these time values for Time sorting.

Kindly Provide any sample code or Any class reference link,So that i can do that.

Answer (score 2):

```
-(NSString *)dateDiff:(NSString *)origDate {
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
    [df setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yy HH:mm:ss VVVV"];
    NSDate *convertedDate = [df dateFromString:origDate];
    [df release];
    NSDate *todayDate = [NSDate date];
    double ti = [convertedDate timeIntervalSinceDate:todayDate];
    ti = ti * -1;
    if(ti < 1) {
        return @"never";
    } else      if (ti < 60) {
        return @"less than a minute ago";
    } else if (ti < 3600) {
        int diff = round(ti / 60);
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d minutes ago", diff];
    } else if (ti < 86400) {
        int diff = round(ti / 60 / 60);
        return[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d hours ago", diff];
    } else if (ti < 2629743) {
        int diff = round(ti / 60 / 60 / 24);
        return[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d days ago", diff];
    } else {
        return @"never";
    }   
}
```

Comment: For seconds, I changed it to return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d seconds ago", (int) ti];  but apart from that seems to work OK.